# Implicitly add to collection

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a Set, and I want to implicitly add another value to the end of that Set when it is called.

For example, I need something like this to work:

```
implicit def addToSet(set: Set[Int]) = set + 4
val s = Set(1, 2, 3)
println(s) // Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**Use case:**

I am building a website (using PlayFramework), and I have about 20-30 Sets of roles which correspond to different pieces of functionality. For each page, only certain roles can access certain features, so I have a bit of functionality each time I need to check role privileges (in pseudocode: `if(role.canAccess(/*name of page*/))`) which checks if the role that the user is logged in as is contained in the Set which corresponds to `/*name of page*/`.

I am now creating a super user which has access to every piece of functionality on every page, so that user's "role" needs to be in every Set. I don't want to have to do this by manually adding this role to every Set because I want this to be scalable and easily maintainable, so I was hoping for a solution which just adds this new super role to each Set automatically behind the scenes.

I'm open to non-implicit answers too, as long as they don't modify the original Sets I already have.

Comment: Implicit def would create an implicit conversion.. so, if you required a Set[Long] nad you provide a Set[Int] it would pick it up...
There is no reason there for the compiler to go and convert that set, so nothing will be done in there.
Just create a small method to be use with your set, if you are using immutable Set you have no issue with changing that, and you will return a NEW set.
Also, implicit conversions are really tempting cause "clean" code, but means you hide what the code really does.

Comment: @FerranJr my current Sets are immutable; I'm fine with returning a new Set. I would rather not manually call a small method every time every one of these Sets is referenced, as they are referenced literally hundreds of times in my application. Preferably, I'd like something to happen behind the scenes without me having to reference it, otherwise it wouldn't be worth it to do this over just adding my new role to each Set manually.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley, IMHO, it would be a bad idea that this kind of things could be done, at first it seems that the code is more _"clean"_, but as Ferran already said it really becomes obscure, and it may get out of hand and cause bugs - for example take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974985/implicit-conversion-from-a-to-somea). I think, you may look for a different approach.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez for now I've done something similar to Raman's suggestion - with this example it'd be something like `object MyObj { implicit class MyClass(in: Set[Int]) { def values = in + 4 } }; import MyObj._; ...` - and I've put `.values` after each of my Sets. I would rather not have touched my original Sets but this is the most clean-looking solution I've come up with for now.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez because this would essentially be a private bit of code and would be pretty small and local to one file, I don't believe it would be an issue in my real-world scenario. I do understand why there is hesitation about what I am trying to do on a larger scale though, and that was certainly an interesting read.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley implicit classes with extension methods are a great idea!, because they are clear and they are explicit in they implicitness _(that sounds weird, but I hope you get what I mean)_. If you want even more typesafety you may create your own type for Roles _(it may be a simple type alias)_ and create the implicit class only for Sets of Roles, and the method could be called something like `thisPlusSuperRole` which will make everything super clear. I know it is a pain in the ass to do that in every place, but is better than black magic which you don't control.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Also, if you are planning to go with the implicit class solution, you may give a look to [**value classes**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), to avoid the cost of instantiating every implicit class.

Comment: Why don't you just abstract `canAccess(role, allowed)` method or something similar in common trait for controllers or something like that. This method could be implemented as `role == SuperAdmin || allowed.contains(role)`

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you are looking for:

```
trait Implicits {
  implicit class AddIntoSet[T](set: Set[T]) {
    def add(t: T): Set[T] = {
      set.+(t)
    }
  }
}


object Solution1 extends App with Implicits {
  val s = Set(1, 2, 3)
  println(s.add(4)) // Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking to not have to call a method manually in order to have that method applied. Ie, I would like to just be able to write `println(s)` and have the method applied without me having to write the `.add(4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, it might not be a very good idea but if you really must, You could try rolling your own `Set` object with slight modifications:

```
import scala.collection.generic.SetFactory
import scala.collection.{GenSet, Set, immutable}

object CustomSet extends SetFactory[Set]{
  def newBuilder[A] = immutable.Set.newBuilder[A]

  def apply[T](elems: T*)(implicit extra: T): Set[T] = {
    val orig: Set[T] = super.apply(elems).flatten
    val withExtra: Set[T] = orig union GenSet(extra)
    withExtra
  }
}

implicit val extraInt: Int = 4
implicit val extraStr: String = "c"

val myNumNewSet: Set[Int] = CustomSet(1,2,3)
val myStrNewSet: Set[String] = CustomSet("a", "b")
```

And these will return:

```
scala> val myNumNewSet: Set[Int] = CustomSet(1,2,3)
myNumNewSet: scala.collection.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val myStrNewSet: Set[String] = CustomSet("a", "b")
myStrNewSet: scala.collection.Set[String] = Set(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using type alias would be acceptable for you?

```
object Roles {
  type Role = Int //Optionally you can use type tagging to make it more type-safe
  type Roles = Set[Role]

  val SuperRole = 4

  def apply(roles: Role*): Roles = {
    Set(SuperRole) ++ roles
  }
}



println(Roles(1,2,3)) // Set(4, 1, 2, 3)
println(Roles() ++ Set(5,6)) // you can also use all methods from Set
```

That has also advantage, that if you use it in any other scope than roles it wouldn't interfere:

```
val idsOfUsers = Set(10,12,22) // Set(10, 12, 22)
val roles = Roles(10,12,22) //Set(4, 10, 12, 22)
```